# How to download DESeq2 in miniconda3 environment?

Tags: r, conda

I created an environment using miniconda3 with the following commands:

```
conda create -n r_ngs r-essentials r-base
source activate r_ngs
```

I needed to download some extra packages and I managed to download biomart and tximport with the following commands.

```
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-tximport
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-biomart
```

However, then I tried to install DESeq2 but I am getting errors. The command and errors are shown below.

```
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-deseq2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                   failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
bioconductor-deseq2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
bioconductor-deseq2 -> r-base[version='>=4.2,<4.3.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='7.2.0.*|>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']

Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
bioconductor-deseq2 -> r-base[version='>=4.2,<4.3.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='7.2.0.*|>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']
bioconductor-deseq2 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']

Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.10 -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0']
bioconductor-deseq2 -> r-base[version='>=4.2,<4.3.0a0'] -> xz[version='5.2.*|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - python=3.10 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

The R version I have in the environment is R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05).
How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an older version of R? This may all work if you use R 4.2 or better.

Comment: Should I create an new environment then and when I do conda create I should specify the version of R? I followed the directions from this link to create the environment and that is the version I ended up with (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/).

Comment: So you're saying when you ran `conda create -n r_ngs r-essentials r-base` it installed R 3.6? That's odd because it looks like the current version of `r-base` is 4.2.2 https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base. What channels are you using? `conda config --show channels`

Comment: That just says:    channels:
  - defaults

Answer (score 0):

Bioconda has very specific channel requirements, namely:

```
conda-forge > bioconda > defaults
```

The best way to manage Conda environments is with YAMLs. One to use DESeq2 might look something like:

**r_ngs.yaml**

```yaml
name: r_ngs
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.2
  - bioconductor-deseq2
  ## additional packages...
```

and create it with

```bash
conda env create -n r_ngs -f r_ngs.yaml
```

Note, it is almost always preferable to declare all dependencies at time of creation of the environment.